# Change Log4j threshold for the duration of a call

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a log4j with several loggers, appenders used in a multi-threaded application. In one scenario, I will try to connect to a remote service. If the connection fails, I will try again repeatedly.

I would like that only the first time log4j uses its original configuration. But for every other subsequent attempts, I want to use a less verbose configuration. This should not change the logging configuration of the other threads that might operate on the same objects. Note that I cannot know in advance which loggers are used inside the call to connect to the remote service.

So, is there a way to alter the logging globally for the duration of one call without changing the behavior of other concurrent threads?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of the API:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html

You can call the setLevel(Level lev) method and do some changes. However, I'm not 100% sure that you won't affect other threads as normally the Logger is based on a class.

I would think that you would have to get a Logger object for each user session, but I'm not 100% sure if it could cause heap issues.

Maybe controlling the output from your code (only send some messages to the log if it's the first attempt for instance).

Regards

Comment: Thanks but setLevel will indeed affect other threads. Otherwise, I do not have access to the code that logs the messages. I can only act upon the log4j configuraton.

Comment: Well, that will be quite difficult as you will then not be able to modify the behaviour of the logger. Unless someone else sees some trick, I would think that it will not be possible to do what you want without touching the source code.